# How to use Agent's parameter in setting Block's behavior

Tags: parameters, delay, anylogic

I am prototyping a Block ( Delay) behavior according to parameter of Agents entering the block.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1bmy.png)
So these are Source block with Batch agents arriving according to the data from the table.
Next is Delay block which release agents on stopDelay() function call.
Currently, I put a call for stDelay function into Source On Exit Action: stDelay(agent);
timeStampStage1End is an agent's parameter determined by data from the table.

**stDelay** ( function)
function's body:

Batch b = b1;

double r = dateToTime( b.timeStampStage1End);

create_StDelayEvent ( r, b);

Arguments: b1, Type: Batch

**StDelayEvent**( dynamic event)

Action:

delay.stopDelay(b);

Arguments: b, Type: Batch

The problem is that model behaves not as it is supposed to do according to the data: significant number of agents is stuck at Delay block.

Could you please give me a hint about the proper way of using Agent's parameter tor model behavior setting?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can ascertain, your error is that `dateToTime` returns a *simulation time*, but when you set up a dynamic event (via `create_StDelayEvent` in your case), you have to specify the *timeout* (i.e., the duration in time from the current moment). So you should be using something like `time() - r` for your dynamic event timeout.

Having said that, this is an overly-complex way of achieving what you want. Instead, just have the required delay time as a Parameter or Variable inside your `Batch` agent, and have the Delay block use that to define the delay time (e.g., delay time of `agent.preCalculatedDelayTime`).

[In general, if the delay time is not actually unique to each individual `Batch` (e.g., certain types/classes of batch have different delay times, but within a type/class the delay time is the same), you could also do other things like define the different timings in an AnyLogic database table and lookup the appropriate value in the Delay block depending on whatever the relevant agent attributes that you need to check against are.]